# Raspberry Pi that reads discreet 24v from I/O controller and adds to a counter?

Tags: gpio

Totally new to Raspberry PI but have an application for work where id like to beable to read discreet 24 volt power and add to a counter on a small display is this possible if so any insight to any additional things I would need to accom

Comment: what's a `discreet 24 V power`? ... what event is being counted?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.